# Sylow $p$-Subgroups and Counting Prime Numbers

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Use the Sylow Theorems to find the number of prime numbers $p$ and $q$ which satisfy the following conditions:

1. $p<q$
2. $q\not\equiv1($mod $p)$,
3. $pq<100$

---

How would the Sylow Theorems apply to this problem? I'm really confused on how to use them in this setting. This problem just seems like a number theory problem that could be solved using Fermat's Theorem. I genuinely don't understand how to use Sylow $p$-subgroups to solve this problem. Any hints, or explanations would be extremely helpful since I find the Sylow Theorems hard to understand in general.

Comment: I agree. By the condition $pq<100$ (in particular, $p\in\{3,5,7\}$ and $q\le 29$), this is a very finite problem, whereas any attempt based on classification of groups of order $<100$ seems to be utterly over-complicated

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on the quickest way to do this using elementary number theory? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: I think you should stop worrying about how to do it and just do it. It's really not very hard. For example, if $p=7$, then $q=11$ or $13$.

Answer (score 2):

By Sylow's theorems, this is all such pairs such that all groups of order $pq$ are cyclic.  I suppose you could then look at a list of all groups of each order to see which of these had only one.  I agree it's a perversely stated problem.